# HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error The requested page cannot (WCF + REST + IIS7 + SSL)

Tags: wcf, rest, iis-7, ssl, https

I am having a "dandy" time trying to get my WCF REST service hosted on IIS with SSL.

Environment: I am testing on a Windows7 box with a local IIS server. I have self-registered a certificate on my dev box and have:

1. Created a site in IIS for the purposes of exposing this WCF service via HTTPS.
2. Created an application under this site and named it "api"
3. Navigated to my site in IIS
4. Clicked 'Bindings...' in the Actions panel on the right.
5. Clicked 'Add'
6. Selected 'https' and selected my certificate.

A lot of the REST plumbing is handled via extensions in WCF using the WcfRestContrib library. While this has been useful from a programming point of view, there is little out there in the way of documentation when something goes wrong.

The error I am currently getting is:

> ```
> Error Summary
>
> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error The requested page cannot
> ```
>
> be accessed because the related
>   configuration data for the page is
>   invalid. Detailed Error Information
>   Module    IIS Web Core
>   Notification  BeginRequest Handler    Not
>   yet determined Error Code 0x8007000d
>   Config Error   Config
>   File  \?\C:\inetpub\eMobile\api\web.config
>   Requested
>   URL   https://172.xx.xx.254:443/api
>   Physical
>   Path  C:\inetpub\eMobile\api Logon
>   Method    Not yet determined Logon
>   User  Not yet determined
>
> ```
> Config Source
>
>    -1: 
>     0:
> ```

I am really not surew what I am doing wrong here. So far I have tried resenting feature delegation for my site but that didn't work. Any ideas? Anything look odd in my web.config?

Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="e1ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=USSV112;Initial Catalog=e1;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="e2ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=USSV112;Initial Catalog=e2;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="204800" executionTimeout="3600"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
    </compilation>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ServiceAnonymityModule" type="WcfRestContrib.Web.ServiceAnonymityModule, WcfRestContrib, Version=1.0.6.107, Culture=neutral"/>
    </httpModules>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Users" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^rest/users/(.*)$"/>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="rest/Users.svc/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules>
      <remove name="ServiceAnonymityModule"/>
      <add name="ServiceAnonymityModule" type="WcfRestContrib.Web.ServiceAnonymityModule, WcfRestContrib, Version=1.0.6.107, Culture=neutral"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="messages" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="d:\Temp\WcfRestContribErrors.log" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
        <listeners>
          <add name="messages" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="d:\Temp\WcfRestContribMessages.log" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <trace autoflush="true"/>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
    <extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="webAuthentication" type="WcfRestContrib.ServiceModel.Configuration.WebAuthentication.ConfigurationBehaviorElement, WcfRestContrib, Version=1.0.6.107, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89183999a8dc93b5" />
        <add name="errorHandler" type="WcfRestContrib.ServiceModel.Configuration.ErrorHandler.BehaviorElement, WcfRestContrib, Version=1.0.6.107, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89183999a8dc93b5" />
        <add name="webFormatter" type="WcfRestContrib.ServiceModel.Configuration.WebDispatchFormatter.ConfigurationBehaviorElement, WcfRestContrib, Version=1.0.6.107, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89183999a8dc93b5" />
        <add name="webErrorHandler" type="WcfRestContrib.ServiceModel.Configuration.WebErrorHandler.ConfigurationBehaviorElement, WcfRestContrib, Version=1.0.6.107, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89183999a8dc93b5" />
      </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="HttpStreamedRest">
          <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="209715200" manualAddressing="true"/>
        </binding>
        <binding name="HttpsStreamedRest">
          <httpsTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="209715200"  manualAddressing="true"/>
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Rest">
          <webAuthentication authenticationHandlerType="WcfRestContrib.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.WebBasicAuthenticationHandler, WcfRestContrib"
            usernamePasswordValidatorType="Engage.Mobile.WebServices.Runtime.SecurityValidator, Engage.Mobile.WebServices"
            requireSecureTransport="false" source="E Mobile" />
          <webFormatter>
            <formatters defaultMimeType="application/json">
              <formatter type="WcfRestContrib.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.Formatters.PoxDataContract, WcfRestContrib"
                mimeTypes="application/xml,text/xml" />
              <formatter type="WcfRestContrib.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.Formatters.DataContractJson, WcfRestContrib"
                mimeTypes="application/json" />
              <formatter type="WcfRestContrib.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.Formatters.FormUrlEncoded, WcfRestContrib"
                mimeTypes="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" />
            </formatters>
          </webFormatter>
          <errorHandler errorHandlerType="WcfRestContrib.ServiceModel.Web.WebErrorHandler, WcfRestContrib" />
          <webErrorHandler logHandlerType="Engage.Mobile.WebServices.Runtime.LogHandler, Engage.Mobile.WebServices" returnRawException="true" exceptionDataContractType="" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks very much like this [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/asmxandxml/thread/fda13fb1-d9af-4db9-b69c-e53ed862677e)

The proposed answer was

> 1. Right click the folder where your site is located: "C:\Users\NAME\SiteName" and selecting Properties
> 2. Select the Security tab and click on Edit
> 3. Add.. and type in "IIS_IUSRS"

Answer (score 1):

I posted a similar answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305821/iis-http-error-500-19/15297241#15297241), and there are similar answers across SO for these errors.

You have a rewrite element in your web.config, and without URL Rewrite installed IIS does not recognise this element and throws the error you currently see. Install [URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) and this should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try enabling tracing on your service to see if the request is reaching the service or failing on IIS itself. If it is reaching your service then tracing would pick up the exact error on where it is failing. To enable tracing follow this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx)