# IIS HTTP Error 500.19

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have installed IIS on my computer for the first time (until now I have worked with the express version), but it's not working properly. When I try to hit a page, it returns this error, which I do not know how to resolve:

> Error Summary 
>  HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
>  The
>   requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration
>   data for the page is invalid.
>  Detailed Error Information
>   Module    IIS Web Core
>  Notification  BeginRequest
>  Handler   Not
>   yet determined
>  Error Code    0x8007000d
>  Config Error    
>   Config File   \?\D:\2008\abcd.Website\web.config
>  Requested
>   URL   http : // localhost:80/abcd.Website
>  Physical
>   Path  D:\2008\ManagerAnticriza.Website
>  Logon Method  Not yet
>   determined
>  Logon User    Not yet determined

Can anyone help me? Is there a way I need to configure IIS after installing it?

Comment: please post the snapshot of Error page, as it contains more information than you posted.

Comment: Have a look at my answer on [HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error][1]. Hope this helps...


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091640/http-error-500-19-internal-server-error/29032247#29032247

Comment: If the line number in the page says 0, then you probably missed an OOB module, https://blog.lextudio.com/jexus-manager-new-hope-to-end-oob-related-500-19-errors-193854de0d4d

Answer (score 60, accepted):

This issue took me the best part of a day to figure out, as I had the exact same code working on another machine in the office.

It turns out that I was missing some features in IIS, and that the web.config I had carried down was looking for these features. I was missing both authentication features and the URL Rewrite module, and as a result IIS believed my web.config was malformed.

There are similar answers across the Internet that mention the URL Rewrite module, so I'd look there first.

Comment: Happened to me on **IIS Express** with VS.NET 2013, too. Turns out a `<rewrite>` section with no rewrite module being present. Commenting out the `<rewrite>` section was sufficient.

Comment: You can install the URL Rewrite module from here: http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Comment: I was also missing "Application Development Features/ASP.NET 4.6"

Comment: Installing URL Rewrite module has fixed my problem. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 5):

installing iis rewrite module helped me here.

[The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216158/the-requested-page-cannot-be-accessed-because-the-related-configuration-data-for)

-Naval

Answer (score 3):

Download and install `.NET CORE Hosting Bundle` to solve the problem.

That's worked for me.

Comment: thanks it worked for me https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/3.1
Install ASP.NET Core Runtime 3.1.17

Answer (score 1):

None of the solutions I'd seen worked for me but I eventually pinned it down to a clash between WSUS (Windows Server Update Service) and the way it was defining compression.  My application pool needed to allow 32 bit applications and that was causing the trouble.  In my case the module listed in the error message was the DynamicCompression module and  I found the solution here so I'm posting it in case it helps anyone else.

https://community.sophos.com/kb/en-us/111319

Answer (score 0):

> because the related configuration data for the page is invalid

This is because your `web.config` is not well formatted, or did not have the correct permissions to be readed.

Error details: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942055

Comment: indeed .. now i have another problem  <br/>Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.<br/>Line 20:   <authentication mode="Forms">

Comment: @user1482442 this is mean that you have place the web.config NOT on the root but in a subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the App Pool to v2.0

[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqYUG.png)

Answer (score 0):

In DotNet Core, I was able to troubleshoot the issue by directly running the dotnet command from within the web.config file.

```
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MyCompany.Service.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
```

Which translates into

```
dotnet ./MyCompany.Service.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

This error may occur for any of the following reasons:

- Not installing the .net version of your project (sdk)
- Not installing dotnet-hosting
- not installing "iis url rewrite"
  and..