# Cannot host web applications

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

1. I have created a new web app using mvc 3 in visual studio 2010. I'm still using aspx view engine.
2. I have copied the files (bin, content, scripts, views, global.asax, web.config) to the C:\inetpub\wwwroot -folder. I have done that manually, using publish -> file system (in VS) and by building deployment package (in VS)
3. I have set applicaton pool in iis 7.5 (win 7 x64) to .net 4.0 and integrated mode.
4. I have created a new site that uses the folder C:\inetpub\wwwroot and app pool above.
5. I try to run the website and I get this:
   6-i set permition for iis user

Error Summary
Internet Information Services 7.5
Error Summary
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
Detailed Error Information
Module  IIS Web Core
Notification    Unknown
Handler Not yet determined
Error Code  0x80070005
Config Error    Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions
Config File \?\C:\Inetpub\vhosts\n-clinic.ir\httpdocs\web.config

Comment: Have you installed MVC3 on the IIS server?

Comment: Is the app pool set to run as a specific user? Check the folders have permissions for that user.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305821/iis-http-error-500-19

Comment: i changed my app pool and create new app pool but not response from my site thjis is my address:n-clinic.ir

Comment: i get this error  http://i.stack.imgur.com/8fxbS.png

Answer (score 0):

What concerns me the most about your error message is the line

> Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions

Sounds like a classic case of permissions on the website directory. Try adding read/write access to 'everyone'. If that fixes it, try to work out the user that is actually being used and readjust your folder permissions accordingly.

The following link might also help track down the cause of your error:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942055

Comment: I can't see the image as I'm at work, is there an error code?

Comment: I can see it now - using my mobile - have you tried running "aspnet_regiis -i" from the cmd prompt of the server? You can run "aspnet_regiis -lv" first to see if everything is installed and valid..