# Getting Internal Server Error 500

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, iis

is I'm Getting generic internal server error 500 while trying to access my Asp.net(4.5) Start page(login.aspx)

The reason is the following code cause the error

```
<rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ff">
                    <match url="supportedhousing/login.aspx" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="supportedhousing/" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

If I remove above code no error.

This question is NOT about above code. Question is  how I can see the real error message.

I tried the following:

```
 <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"> </customErrors>
     <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
</system.web>
```

and also

```
 <system.webServer>
   <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>
 </system.webServer>
```

Still I'm getting same generic error internal server error 500.

I checked Event logs but no error there.

Interestingly If I try to browse the page directly on web server I get error 500.19 but that is also cryptic.

Comment: From where are you logging in? What mode is IIS in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot of problem like this. There is no error log. Did you install iis rewrite module?
Also this config not working in iis express for debuging.

Comment: If you read my question ,question is not about the rewrite code. I am using iis .

Comment: <rewrite> tag only working with iis rewrite module: [link](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)

Comment: Also you check this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305821/iis-http-error-500-19)