# ASP.NET Core 3.1 using api in controller route causes HTTP Error 500.19

Tags: c#

This is the strangest thing I have seen in awhile. I created 2 solutions. Both where created identically.

I removed the `WeatherController` and added a `HealthController` in both.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class HealthController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string Get()
    {
        return $"Mobile Server {Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")}";
    }
}
```

Is so simple, yet if I run the project in IISExpress, I get a 500.19 Error when I try to access the route from a browser.

If I run it in Kestrel, everything works just fine. Also, if I change the word api in the route to anything else, it also works just fine.

In my second solution, I am not having any issues at all.

I'm totally confused...

Comment: Can you check your config file ?

Comment: When I got this error in the past it tended to be an issue with the configuration of the module in the IIS (usually in combination with a missing URL rewrite module). You might want to take a look at this question with the accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305821/iis-http-error-500-19